# How to create certificate authority in KeyChain? 

Tags: iphone

While I try to submit my app, I accidentally deleted certificate autority in KeyChain.
How do I recover that? There is certificate authority creation menu, but I don't know what info
I have to fill.

Do I have to reinstall Lion? How do I reinstall KeyChain alone?

Comment: What certificate did you delete?

Comment: I deleted everything. KeyChain says that I have to make certifacate authority.

Comment: Interesting, what happens when you log onto the apple member center and download your certificates again from there and try and install them?

Comment: I deleted development certificate and distribution certificate also. After several trial to submit, I failed. I decided to start from scratch. I have to generate CSR by KeyChain first to request distribution certificate. Because I cannot Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority in KeyChain, I cannot make certificate in member center.

Comment: Maybe, you misunderstand my reply. There are 182 certificate authority in system root. I didn't delete them at all. But I cannot choose that.